# Add character after specific character in string

Tags: c

Task is to add `*` after every `*` in string:

```
Input:*fsd*fds*fds*f
Output: **fsd**fds**fds**f
```

I found this and i am trying to replace every `*` with `**`
But it wont work.

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include<stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {

    char x[256];

    scanf("%s", &x);

    for (char* p = x; p = strchr(p, '*'); ++p) {
        *p = '*';
    }

    printf("%s", x);

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

it only works when i use one char in this line

```
*p = '*';
```

but when i use more it does not work.

so  `*p = '**';` does not work.

Thanks for any help or hint.

Comment: You cannot use that syntax. Single quotes are for a single character. You will need a strncpy or some such function.

Comment: when you replacing `*` with `**` you are writing two characters in place of one, so it replaces the next character after `*`.

Comment: After you find an `*`, you'll have to shift every `char` after it to the right before adding another `*`.

Comment: "Replacing" `*` with `**` means _inserting a char (the 2nd `*`). That means the string gets longer and you first have to move up the charaters by one (and make sure there is enough memory for that).

Comment: Thanks that strncpy looks like easy solution.

Comment: Also you can't declare `'**'` in C. You have to use `"**"`. Single quote are for `char`, double quotes for `char *`.

Comment: The `&` in `scanf("%s", &x);` is wrong: `x` by itself is already (converted to) a pointer to the correct destination (`&x` is a pointer to someplace you don't want to mess with)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comments, when you replacing `*` with `**` you are writing two characters in place of one, so it replaces the next character after `*`. One otherway would be to take another empty array and copy elements from input string, when you find `*` you can insert two `**` Following snippet shows one potential solution.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {

    char x[256],y[256];
    unsigned index = 0;

    scanf("%s", x);

    for (unsigned i = 0; i < strlen(x); i++) {

        y[index++] = x[i];

        if(x[i] == '*')
            y[index++] = '*';
    }

    y[index] = '\0';

    printf("%s", y);

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The `&` in `scanf("%s", &x);` is wrong: `x` by itself is already (converted to) a pointer to the correct destination (`&x` is a pointer to someplace you don't want to mess with)

Comment: very poor solution

Answer (score 0):

It's easier to write the code if you just read one character at a time like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  while (1) {
    int input = fgetc(stdin);
    if (input == EOF) { break; }
    if (input == '*') { fputc('*', stdout); }
    fputc(input, stdout);
  }
}
```

Also, since we are not dealing with memory allocations, arrays, or strings here, it is a lot easier to write safe code that will not suffer from buffer overflow bugs.

Note: Recent versions of the C standard put `return 0;` implicitly at the end of your `main` function so you don't have to write it yourself.