# Add character after specific character in string (max 1string,array)

Tags: c

I need to put * after every * in string

```
Input:*tret*ret*re*ter
Output:**tret**ret**re**ter
```

Well i have code that works but problem is that i can use only one string(array).
And i used two.

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include<stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {

    char x[256], y[256], z = 0;

    scanf("%s", x);

    for (char i = 0; i < strlen(x); i++) {

        y[z++] = x[i];

        if (x[i] == '*')
            y[z++] = '*';
    }

    y[z] = '\0';

    printf("%s\n", y);

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

I will be thankful for any advice how to make it with only one string.

I even try but it makes soem chars disappear

```
int main() {

    char x[256], z = 0;

    scanf("%s", x);

    for (char i = 0; i < strlen(x); i++) {



        if (x[i] == '*') {
            x[++i] = '*';
        }
    }


    printf("%s\n",x);

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What are the exact constraints of this exercise?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add character after specific character in string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53121470/add-character-after-specific-character-in-string)

Comment: U get user input(string). And then add * to every * in string. But it can be done only with 1 string

Comment: Not only possible that is my too :D But later i realize that i cant use two arrays

Comment: @mlp You can just delete comments. :-) (There should be a (X) button after your name that you can click.)

Comment: @melpomene Thanks - the (X) only appears as the mouse cursor hovers over the comment, and I had missed that earlier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I will be thankful for any advice how to make it with only one string.

**Algorithm**

Count the number of occurrences of `'*'` --> `star_count`.

Note the length of the string --> `length`

Ensure `length + star_count` < 256, else buffer is too small.

Loop from the end to the beginning.

Set `src` to end of string.  (The null character)

Set `dest` to end of `src + star_count`.

// ***

Set *dest = null character.

While not done (`src` != beginning):
- Assign `*dest = *src` and decrement both pointers.
- Conditionally assign  `*dest = '*'`, decrement `dest`.

---

[@Ian Abbott](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53123186/add-character-after-specific-character-in-string-max-1string-array/53123340?noredirect=1#comment93141631_53123340) offers a nice improvement.  Loop until pointers match.

From ***

While dest > src
- Assign `*dest = *src` and decrement both pointers.
- Conditionally assign  `*dest = '*'`, decrement `dest`.

Comment: Thank your very much :)

Comment: The `while` condition `src != dest` would also work, and it would terminate earlier unless the first character is `'*'`.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should wonder why only one single array. IMHO, if it is simpler with two arrays, stick there.

Next you use char as indexes. Please don't unless you have a strong reason to. A decent compiler should warn you because it can be a cause of hard to detect errors. For example, if you implementation uses signed 8 bits char, the max value is 127 and not 255. So if the string contains 128 characters and the terminating null, the loop `for (char i = 0; i < strlen(x); i++) {` is an endless one. Because 127+1 is likely to be -128 (undefined behaviour, but very common).

And as you know the size of the `x` array, you should use a limited `scanf` and test its return value:

```
if (scanf("%255s", x) != 1) {
    // process error
    ...
}
```

For the rest, @chux's answer gives you the only way to extend a string in place:

- scan it once to find its final size
- process it starting from the end

Answer (score -1):

When you find an `*` character, you'll have to shift every byte after it to the right to make room for an additional `*` character.  Below is one such implementation:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    char x[256] = {'\0'}; // NUL Terminate Every Character

    printf("Enter String: ");
    scanf("%s", x);

    for(int i = 0; i < strlen(x); i++)
    {
        if(x[i] == '*')
        {
            for(int j = strlen(x) + 1; j > i; j--)
                x[j] = x[j - 1]; // Shift Every Byte, Starting With Last, To Right
            x[++i] = '*';
        }   
    }

    printf("%s\n", x);
    return 0;
}
```

**Execution**

```
Enter String: *hi*buddy*
**hi**buddy**
```

Comment: That's a lot less efficient than chux's algorithm. Your code is O(n^2).